# Opening start menu items asks to save exe file

Tags: windows-7

My younger brother was playing around with my windows 7 system. And now I have a problem. Whenever I try to open a program from start menu, it opens up a new tab in firefox and says 'You have chosen to open: ' and so and so app and asks to save the file. I have to save that file and open the exe to run the app. What could have happened here? I am attaching image of how they ask me. This happens every time I open a program from the start menu.[image]

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you.  Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like he accidentally associated the `.exe` file extension with your web browser.  As a result, you would need to reset it to the default configuration.

Under similar circumstances, I would download the registry fix related to both `.exe` files and `.lnk` files from the following location and run them on your system:

[Restore Default Windows 7 File Extension Type Associations](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I actually fixed it by following instructions here. http://ccm.net/forum/affich-519840-all-my-icons-change-to-internet-explorer. Sorry for the delay as well. I was not in town.

Comment: Just so you know, the section within my answer from last week that recommended you use the `.lnk` registry fix does the same thing that is described within the article you referenced.  Ultimately, as long as your machine is back to normal, that's what really counts.  If you want to detail your fix action within your own answer and mark that accordingly, you can do that, also.